# Purpose of backslash in nginx map configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, fail2ban

I'm using a map configuration to block IP addresses with nginx + fail2ban

The [sample configuration](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/action.d/nginx-block-map.conf) genrator code in fail2ban repo looks like this :

```
...
_echo_blck_row = printf '\%%s 1;\n' "<fid>"
actionban = %(_echo_blck_row)s >> '%(blck_lst_file)s'; %(blck_lst_reload)s
...
```

Note the leading backslash in `\%%s 1;\n`. It creates a file with IP addresses that have a leading backslash before each IP address i.e. it dumps a file like this

```
\127.0.0.1    1;
```

instead of simply

```
127.0.0.1    1;
```

Both the configurations are correct. What's the purpose of the backslash at the start of the IP address in this file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map):

> If a source value matches one of the names of special parameters
> described below, it should be prefixed with the “\” symbol.

So it's unnecessary (but harmless) for values such as `127.0.0.1`, but it defends against using hostnames such as `default`, `hostnames`, `volatile` or `include`, which are considered "special parameters" within the `map` block.